# Create channels in DiscordJs v14

Tags: discord, discord.js

So i upgraded to DiscordJs v14 and i want to create a command that creates a channel but i none of the codes i found online are working

Error:

```
/home/runner/discord-js-v14-1-2/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.cjs:293
        throw new DiscordAPIError.DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
```

Comment: Show us the code you've written otherwise it's hard for us to tell what you did wrong. According to the error you did not provide a name for the channel. Instead of copy and pasting code from others try to learn the library and language yourself. This will greatly benefit you in the long run

Answer (score 0):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/CategoryCreateChannelOptions

Check out discordjs docs first!

Answer (score 0):

Since Discordjs v14 you have to specify the name as a parameter !

Do

```js
interaction.guild.channels.create({
  name: "NameOfTheChannel",
  type: 'text',
})
```

Instead of

```js
interaction.guild.channels.create("nameOfTheChannel", {
  type: 'text',
})
```